# How could I properly Collect a Set<String> by using streams and map in this operation?

Tags: java, java-stream

I think I can make this simplier but can not figure out how to properly use .map() here and then Collect to a Set, can you help?

I am using parallel stream so that this operation is done faster, each tree has nodes but I just want all their names without repeating (using Set)... The nodeName is composed of the id+version

**My working code which correctly returns `Set<String>`:**

```
// Set for not repeating node names between trees
NavigableSet<String> nodeNames = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>();
trees.parallelStream().forEach(
        tree -> tree.getNodes().forEach(node -> nodeNames.add(node.getId() + node.getVersion())));
```

**I was trying the following to achieve .map() usage:**

```
trees.parallelStream()
            .map(tree -> tree.getNodes().stream().map(node -> node.getId() + node.getVersion()))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

But the collection returned is `Set<Stream<String>>`, I need `Set<String>`

Comment: Try `.flatMap()` instead of `map`, that'll flatten the results down to just one Set of Strings

Comment: @SIMULATAN would appreciate if you can post answer showing how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```java
trees.parallelStream()
  .flatMap(tree -> tree.getNodes().stream().map(node -> node.getId() + node.getVersion()))
  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

That will flatten down the result from the `map` to have all results in one long `Set` rather than in a `Set` of `Stream`s.

Comment: Thank you, there is a problem I just noticed that NavigableSet<String> is not compatible with Set<String>, do you know if there is a way to make the Collector return NavigableSet? If not it is okay I will just use Set<String>, think im not losing anything from the NavigableSet, was using it mostly for the thread safety with the ConcurrentSkipListSet, but I believe Collectors will take care of thread safety

Comment: In that case, use `Collectors.toCollection(NavigableSet::new)` (but make sure to actually use your *implementation*, not the *interface*).

Comment: Thank you, yes it worked: Collectors.toCollection(ConcurrentSkipListSet<String>::new)

Comment: @BugsOverflow do you really need a `ConcurrentSkipListSet` or would a plain `TreeSet` also do?

Comment: @Holger I think TreeSet would also work with this approach, because Collectors is taking care of the thread safeness, the only reason I was using ConcurrentSkipListSet is because of the Thread safe attribute it has when doing the inserts while using parallelStream

Comment: @BugsOverflow that’s why I asked. If you don’t need thread safety after the stream operation, you can use `Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new)`. The collector doesn’t have the [`CONCURRENT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.Characteristics.html#CONCURRENT) characteristic, so it wouldn’t exploit concurrency abilities of a `ConcurrentSkipListSet` during the Stream operation anyway. You’d have to construct your own collector (or use `toConcurrentMap` and take the `keySet` afterwards) if you want to collect concurrently.